# Powershell SendKeys not working for Esc+Ctrl

Tags: powershell, sendkeys

My initial intention was to toggle show/hide of windows 8 taskbar. As this cant be done without registry mods, I have decided to use third party app ("Hide Taskbar") - it works perfectly switching show/hide with CTRL+ESC combo.

I want to make it automatic in some cases using PowerShell. Unfortunatelly, the script I always used for such purposes:

```
add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{ESC}")
```

doesnt seam to work. No error, just nothing. For example the same but with ALT: ("%{ESC}") works.

Would be gratefull for suggestions, what have I missed?